# Python Flask: Having multiple definitions or storing everything in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I currently have something like this

```
def get_graphnet_medication_issued(detail_id):
    """
    Getting the Graphnet issued medication
    """
    data = get_graphnet_api_request(detail_id,'/gp/patients/','/gp-medications/issued')
    return data

def get_graphnet_medication_repeat(detail_id):
    """
    Getting the Graphnet repeat medication
    """
    data = get_graphnet_api_request(detail_id,'/gp/patients/','/gp-medications/repeat')
    return data
```

For each REST API call we can make, we do a new 'def' which is all well and good for the dozen or so we have but I started to think about scalability and what would happen if we had hundreds

Would putting the values in a `dict` be any better?

```
endpoints = {
    "issued":{
        "pre":"/gp/patients/",
        "post":"/gp-medications/issued"
    },
    "repeat":{
        "pre":"/gp/patients/",
        "post":"/gp-medications/repeat"
    },
    "random":{
        "pre":"/a/b/c/d",
        "post":"/e/f/g/h"
    }
}
```

Then calling

```
get_graphnet_api_request(detail_id,'issued')
```

Then within that `def` reference the dictionary and the necessary keys/values?

Please note that the values of `pre` and `post` can differ dramatically. In the above, it just so happens they are very similar.

Which way would be deemed as more scalable? Is there another better way? I now if we're going to have hundreds it's going to be a large amount of work anyway but just thought storing them in a `dict` might be better

Comment: If the only thing changing is that last word in the URL, just pass that in as parameter and concatenate it? `def get_graphnet_medication(detail_id, status): return get_graphnet_api_request(detail_id, '/gp/patients/', '/gp-medications/' + status)`

Comment: `pre` and `post` would be changing. Just so happens the two examples I've used have a very similar structure. I will update the post

Answer (score 1):

Sure, there are many ways to [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) that code. The dict approach is very sensible. But it can also be sensible to have each call as a separate function to aid discoverability. So as an alternative, use a function factory function:

```
def graphnet_medication(pre, post):
    def get_graphnet_medication(detail_id):
        return get_graphnet_api_request(detail_id, pre, post)
    
    return get_graphnet_medication


get_graphnet_medication_issued = graphnet_medication('/gp/patients/', '/gp-medications/issued')
get_graphnet_medication_repeat = graphnet_medication('/gp/patients/', '/gp-medications/repeat')
...
```

This is basically a specialised version of [`partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial). Maybe do some combination of both approaches.